# How to retrieve only the labels?

Tags: apache-age

Is there a query to retrieve only the labels for nodes and edges from a graph in a database? I know a query to retrieve the data information for nodes and edges from a graph, but it retrieves all the information. I'm wondering if there is a query to retrieve only the label information for nodes and edges.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only the labels with cypher, you can execute the following command:

```sql
-- showing the vertex labels only
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH (v)
RETURN label(v)
$$) AS (vertex_label agtype);

-- showing the edge labels only
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH ()-[e]-()
RETURN label(e)
$$) AS (edge_label agtype);
```

And you can also retrieve it like everyone stated here:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will show you all the labels for all graphs under your database:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have a Vertex With a single label `v` and properties `name`. We can use the query

`Select * from cypher('demo' ,$$ Match(v:p) Return v $$  ) as (vertex agtype);`

to return all the labels and their properties e.g

| vertex |
| --- |
| `{"id": 9288674321451649, "label": "p", "properties": {"name": "John"}}::vertex` |

Now when we only need the labels we run the query:

```
Select * from cypher('demo' ,$$ Match(v:p) Return labels(v) $$  ) as (vertex agtype);
```

to get the following:

| vertex |
| --- |
| `"p"` |

And you can also do:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```